# heap function in py

Tags: list

I'm trying to create heap function for a tree, and this is what I have so far.

```
def imh(tree):
    if tree == None:
        return True
    if tree.L and tree.R:
        if tree.L.L==None and tree.L.R==None:
            if tree.L.val < tree.val:
                return False
        if tree.R.L==None and tree.L.R==None: 
            if tree.R.val < tree.val:
                return False
    if tree.L == None:
        imh(tree.R)
    if tree.R == None:
        imh(tree.L)
```

Though, my logic is flawed and I'm not sure what to add - I've been working on this for a while and have considered a thorough range of logical tests, but I'm sure it can be done with much less complexity..

Comment: You should add ``print`` statements and run it on a small input to see what's wrong. Unrelatedly, it's better to write ``is None`` than ``== None``.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more flexible algorithm, which can be easily generalized to non-binary trees:

```
def imh(tree):
    if tree is None:
        return True
    for subtree in ( tree.L, tree.R ):
        if subtree is not None and (subtree.val < tree.val or not imh(subtree)):
            return False
    return True
```

And for the functional-programming fans, here's the same thing as a one-liner:

```
return tree is None or \
    all(  subtree is None or (subtree.val >= tree.val and imh(subtree))
          for subtree in ( tree.L, tree.R )  )
```

Comment: This is really nice and brief, but it doesn't handle the invalid case of nodes not having a sibling but having children. Makes it a little more annoying :/.

Answer (score 0):

You are violating the principles of recursion with the following:

```
if tree.L.L==None and tree.L.R==None:
```

You should only be managing one level at a time, per recursive step, not peeking multiple levels down the tree.

You don't mention what this function does, but I'm assuming it's supposed to test whether the tree is a valid min-heap which has the following properties:

1. A binary heap is a complete binary tree; that is, all levels of the tree, except possibly the last one (deepest) are fully filled.
2. All nodes are less than or equal to each of its children

Your approach should be as follows: At each step, you have your current `tree` node. You should only check whether two children exist or not, and if so, whether both values are greater than the current node.

If so, continue traversing the tree in an in-order fashion. If not, return False.

```
"""
has_sibling keeps tracks of whether all parent nodes so far
had a sibling or not. If a parent node didn't have a sibling,
but has children, then we will return `False` for this scenario.
"""
def imh(tree, has_sibling=True):
    if tree is None:
        return True
    if not has_sibling:
        return False
    if tree.L and tree.L.val < tree.val:
        return False
    if tree.R and tree.R.val < tree.val:
        return False
    return imh(tree.L, tree.R is not None and has_sibling) and imh(tree.R, tree.L is not None and has_sibling)
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this but the line `if tree.L.val > tree.val or tree.R.val > tree.val:` yields more accurate results as `if tree.L.val < tree.val or tree.R.val < tree.val:` -- but then at the same time it still yields incorrect results -- for example a tree with only 1 layer and 1 leaf returns the opposite result

Comment: I edited the question to include the data I was trying to insert above

Comment: I don't think those are correct min-heap trees. By definition each node must have 0 or 2 childen (complete binary tree). It cannot have just one child.

Comment: @MartinKonecny sure it can. How else would you represent a heap with 2 elements?

Comment: Is there a way the function can handle these types of data too?

Comment: Yep you are correct, it complicates the function a bit, but added a check where a node without a sibling needs to be a leaf node.

Comment: If the sibling-logic is indeed relevant to OP, it is worth pointing out the last example (3--1) is also an invalid structure: the last level is always filled left-to-right, i.e. L must exist if R exists.